# how to solve strange behavior of ui tab bar in ios 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating an application in which I am using the tab bar with 3 tabs. Everything works fine in iOS 6, but in iOS 7 when I click on tab 3 it checks if user is logged in or not.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     appdelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
     appdelegate.strLoginMessage=@"setting";
     BOOL isLogin= [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"isLogin"]intValue ];
     if (isLogin) 
     {
         [self webService_Count];
     }
     else
     {
         appdelegate.showLoginBack=NO;
         ViewController *view=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
    }
}
```

If user is not login then i send it to the login page. But from here if user taps on the tab 3 it go to setting page without login. And if user again clicks tab 3 it shows black screen. I can't understand why?

This is how I setup my tab bar in `appDelegate`

```
self.nav= [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.nav1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.messageviewcontroller];
self.nav2=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.settingviewController];
```

in nav1 and nav2 i check if the user login or not in view will appear.

Comment: where are you setting the object for "isLogin" in NSUserDefaults? Did you check whether your boolean isLogin gets the correct value or not from the NSUserDefaults?

Comment: i set it when user log in sucess fully in login page. just a reminder that this works perfectly in ios < 7 . the problem is in ios= 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if user is not login then show login screen as a root view instead of push it into current navigation controller:

```
ViewController *view = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = view;
```

Comment: i tried this before but the problem is i have to check the user login in two tabs and then navigate the user to the view from which he login,EX if he login from tab 2 then he should go to message and if he login with tab 3 then go to setting, icouldnt make this happen last time.

Comment: Then you should show login screen as modal view which will cover whole screen so user cannot navigate to elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I can only imagine `viewWillAppear:` is not being called on each subsequent tap of the UITabBarItem.

Have you set a breakpoint in the method to check?

If it is in fact thew `viewWillAppear:` method not being called, I would suggest placing this code somewhere which is called on each tap on the UITabBarItem.

Comment: ya view will appear does not call every time.and i checked that the view controller is also not set in tab bar stack.

Comment: Are you doing this with a story board or in the AppDelegate?

Answer (score 1):

following solve my problem.i changes the root view after login and assiged the login page as root view at logout time.

```
 ViewController *view=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:view] animated:YES];

            MessageLoginViewController *message=[[MessageLoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MessageLoginViewController" bundle:nil];
            [appdelegate.nav1 setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:message]];
```